# Where can I find the reference for Amal-e-Kathir?

Tags: salat, reference-request

I'm looking for a reference from which the definition of Amal-e-Kathir (Amal-e-Kaseer) for salaat has been derived/debated in Fiqah.
As far as online searches go, I have come across a site which mentions `Raddul Muhtar p.385 v.2` & `Taqrir Abu Dawud p.331 v.2` but I cannot find any place online where I can read the actual contents of the referenced texts.

I am looking for the mentioned texts online or preferably some direct reference to Qur'an/Hadith/Fiqah from where amal-e-kathir is defined. I will highly appreciate if the provided references could be consulted online or in other soft forms.

Answer (score -2):

If you understand arabic, you can have a look to it:
http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?ID=1&idfrom=1&idto=8624&bk_no=27

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid I cannot read Arabic but I will try to find someone local who can.

Comment: If you want "some direct reference to Qur'an/Hadith/Fiqah" you have very little choice in english... Even some translation are sometimes wrong. The best explanation in english is : _The Fuqahaa have defined Amal-e-Kathir as conducting oneself in such a way that an onlooker would think the person is not in Salaat. That is generally the case when both hands are used to do something in Salaat._ [link](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/13724.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid you are right. I was just hoping that the well known books may be translated in other languages just like Hadith.
I am already aware of the definition of Amal-e-Kathir; I wanted to read references from which this definition was originally derived.
P.S. I didn't down-vote your answer.